# why does this function converge pointwise

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/intro_analysis_pdf/ch9.pdf

Example 9.4:

$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}2n^2x,  & \text{if 0 ≤ x ≤ 1/(2n)} \\
2n^2(1/n-x), & \text{if $1/2n$ < x < 1/n }\\
0, & \text{if $1/n$ ≤  x < 1 }\\
\end{cases}$

I don't understand why it converges to $0$ when $0 < x \le 1$ as stated in the link.

Comment: A function is not something that converges.  A sequence of functions on the other hand ...

Comment: Oops I meant sequence of functions.

Comment: Not to late to edit the title

Answer (score 3):

Given any $0<x\le 1$, pick $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $1/n_0<x$.  Then we have $f_n(x)=0$ for $n\ge n_0$.  Thus, the limit of $f_n(x)$ as $n\to\infty$ is zero.